# I need to simplify a string without actually changing the numbers (positive and negative signs, parentheses, etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am creating a program that needs to have a way of "doctoring" a numerical equation. It needs to be able to simplify to the numbers and the basic numerical equation, without extra parentheses and negative and positive signs. Example:

```
var input = '[doctor] 2+-(-(2))'
var doctorPositive = input.search('[doctor]')
if (doctorPositive > -1) {
    var deleteDoc = input.replace('[doctor]', '')
    // Code here
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = doctored;
}
```

I need deleteDoc which is currently equal to;

```
'2+-(-(2))'
```

to become:

```
'2+2"
```

I need this to work for almost any numerical equation. It cannot change any variables within the equation however. I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like homework.

This will work for the  1 input you provided and probably a few other simple strings:

```js
'2+-(-(2))'.replaceAll('(', '').replaceAll(')', '').replaceAll('--', '+').replaceAll('++', '+')
```

Comment: What equations would it not work for? I notice you replace all of parentheses, would that be a problems in an equation when those parentheses would actually affect the outcome?

Comment: Basically, what I am asking, could your program work with the following program;    
1-(2+7) where it matters whether or not the parentheses are there? Is it possible to achieve something like this with a regular expression?

Comment: Also, if you had a number like this two '---2' (I don't know why you would if you did) would the program still work. Is there a way to tell the program if there is a group of addition signs in general that this can be replaced with one addition sign and if there is an even number of negative signs this can also be replaced with a positive sign and if there is an odd number of negative signs then it can be replaced with a single negative sign.